# Как записать в список словарей в csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

web = input()

url = (('https://rozetka.com.ua/search/?section_id=&section=&text=')+ web)

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

product_links = (tag.get('href') for tag in soup.select('.g-i-tile-i-title a'))

def get_product_info(url):
    data = dict()
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data['link'] = soup.find(class_='novisited breadcrumbs-link').get('href'[-4])
    data['name'] = soup.find('h1').text
    data['price'] = soup.find(class_='detail-price-uah').text if soup.find(class_='detail-price-uah') else None
  #  data['img_main'] = soup.find(id='landingImage').get('data-old-hires')

    return data

products_data = []
for link in product_links:
    print('Parse ' + link)
    products_data.append(get_product_info(link))
    time.sleep(1)

    print(products_data)
```

Comment: Подробнее пишите, пожалуйста. Например, что такое cvs? Concurrent Versions System — система одновременных версий? И еще, `записать в список cvs` или `записать список в cvs`. Не думаю, что вам нужно cvs записывать в список, так что скорее всего вы хотели список сохранить как csv :)

Comment: Хочу что бы список сохранялся в cvs файл . Не знаю просто как это реализовать

Comment: @Tema что такое cvs файл?

Answer (score 1):

У вас список из словарей и его нужно сохранить в `csv`.

Для этого лучше всего использовать [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

```
import csv

...

# Собираем ключи (столбцы) из словаря первого элемента списка
keys = products_data[0].keys()

# Открываем файл для записи
with open('products_data.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    # Записываем
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(products_data)
```

Comment: Ссылок на товар нету пропали

Comment: @Tema, а в products_data они были? Выведите products_data перед тем как будет в csv записано и убедитесь что там ссылки были. Если ссылки были, но в csv они не попали, приведите пожалуйста пример данных в products_data, чтобы смог самостоятельно проверить

Comment: `products_data = []
for link in product_links:
    print('Parse ' + link)
    products_data.append(get_product_info(link))
    time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Этот код у вас и так в вопросе. Я про другое спрашивал, прочтите, внимательно :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# ...

product_links = (tag.get('href') for tag in soup.select('.g-i-tile-i-title a'))

def get_product_info(url):
    data = dict()
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    data['link'] = soup.find(class_='novisited breadcrumbs-link').get('href'[-4])
    data['name'] = soup.find('h1').text
    data['price'] = soup.find(class_='detail-price-uah').text if soup.find(class_='detail-price-uah') else None
  #  data['img_main'] = soup.find(id='landingImage').get('data-old-hires')

    return data

with open('link.csv', 'w') as g:
    print('link, name, price', file=g)

    for link in product_links:
        prod = get_product_info(link)
        print("{}, {}, {}".format(* [j for i,j  in   [ [k, v] for k,v in prod.items() ]]).replace('\u2009',' '), file=g)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```